# USING statement use cases in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to know in which specific cases to use the USING statement, which is its main functionality when including it in the code.

In my case I am scheduling a job for the university, the project is about registering computers with their different data, I am currently preparing the database, but the professor recommends this sentence and I would like to know more about it

Comment: "Give me list of use cases" (or any other list) is generally off-topic on SO as too broad. The question is instead closed as duplicate of something that may relate to what you are looking for... which is somewhat equivalent to closure as "needs more focus" in this case. Note that adding unrelated text unrelated to the problem like "the professor recommends this sentence and I would like to know more about it", "thanks", "new to ..." is against the guidance on posting questions. Some explanation how question relates to " I am currently preparing the database" may have been more useful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/statements#the-using-statement